# Apply Assimp postprocessing on in-memory mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

How can I load a mesh in Assimp, edit the vertices, and then let assimp recalculate the vertices and do other postprocessing?

The importer can import scenes and supports some flags, amongst them a flag to generate normals. However, after I load the mesh, I edit the mesh a bit (add some wrinkles, nothing really special) and would like to recalculate the normals of the mesh, using Assimp. However, I can't put a mesh back into Assimp. As far as I can tell, only the importer can apply postprocessing and I can't add meshes to the importer, and there are no functions to postprocesses in-memory meshes.

How can I apply Assimp's postprocessing to vertex data I generated in my program?

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you did that? How much editing do you want to attempt?

Comment: I can't try anything: I can't find the functions that would do what I want to do. The Importer has an ImporterPimpl which has an editable scene, but I obviously shouldn't touch that (it's explicitly noted in the documentation not to do this, and the ImporterPimpl type is incomplete on purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this function was available at the time you asked the question, but at this time you can find the following references in the [assimp documentation:](http://www.assimp.org/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html#details)

#### Assimp::Importer Class Reference

```
const aiScene * ApplyPostProcessing (unsigned int pFlags)
// Apply post-processing to an already-imported scene.
```

There is also a [C-API style function](http://www.assimp.org/lib_html/cimport_8h.html#a683b19fdda7fec063d07a412268a7a24) in `cimport.h`

#### cimport.h File Reference

```
ASSIMP_API const aiScene * aiApplyPostProcessing (const aiScene *pScene, unsigned int pFlags)
//Apply post-processing to an already-imported scene.
```

Comment: It's a good find, thanks. I don't think that function was there then. I was hoping to apply post-processing without the importer though, but I guess I can edit the scene and its meshes inside assimp.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do the exact same thing (applying those postprocessing options without having to use the `Importer` class), but I don't think that is actually possible at the moment. They are very good at accepting pull-requests, though.